# How to get radian6 Api KEY though I got registered app?

Tags: java, authentication, api-key, social-media

I am looking for how to get the API key of radian6 .
Doing a POC that has to make a call to radian6 api 
as part of this  I have tried registering app in radian6 at this link
http://socialcloud.radian6.com/

This is how http://socialcloud.radian6.com/member/register i signup and registered app .But I didnot get to see any key under Key tab  in fact it says no application keys created yet

Can any one please let me know how do i get api KEY for radian6
Any help appreciated

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

In the reference guide [here](http://socialcloud.radian6.com/docs/read/Getting_Started) describe the authentication flow for obtain the token:

What you need to get started:

A valid user account login (username and password) to the Marketing Cloud system.
A unique application key for your application (Obtainable from your favorite Marketing Cloud contact).

I think you are looking for the  application key so the doc suggest to contact the Marketing Cloud contact.  We contact the Radian6 API Support.

Hope this help and you had already solved your issue!